# Is software provided by Amazon free to use in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-marketplace

I opened a free tier account in AWS EC2 and created a Linux instance.

Do I need to pay to Amazon for installing and using Tomcat or is it free for an year?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless otherwise stated, EC2 is billed only by the computing power you use (storage, ram, processor, network, etc).

You mentioned Tomcat, which as many other free software offered in linux distributions, can be freely installed regardless of where you run it.

Make sure you review and understand the free tier restrictions before continuing running the instance you've launched.

Answer (score 1):

Free tier is applicable for 750 hours / month for Linux & Windows any micro instance per account. Since Tomcat is open source, you can use it for free.